# How to use tags on VCS repository to get catched by Composer?

Tags: git, version-control, composer-php, repository

I forked on my github account [this repository](https://github.com/calcinai/rubberneck). The forked version is [here] and named `devgiants/filesystem-notification`.

I made a [0.0.2 tag](https://github.com/devgiants/filesystem-notifications/tree/0.0.2) on my forked version.

Now, on [another package](https://github.com/devgiants/filesystem-gpio), named `devgiants/filesystem-gpio` I set want to set `devgiants/filesystem-notification` as dependency :

```
  "repositories": [
    {
      "type": "vcs",
      "url": "https://github.com/devgiants/filesystem-notifications"
    }
  ],
  "require": {
    "php": "^7.0",
    "devgiants/filesystem-notifications": "dev-master#0.0.2"
  }
```

Finally, if I try a `composer req devgiants/filesystem-gpio` on an empty directory, I get following errors from composer :

```
Problem 1
    - Installation request for devgiants/filesystem-gpio ^0.2.8 -> satisfiable by devgiants/filesystem-gpio[0.2.8].
    - devgiants/filesystem-gpio 0.2.8 requires devgiants/filesystem-notifications dev-master#0.0.2 -> no matching package found.
```

Why my tag isn't found?

Comment: Show content of `composer.json` of your **root** application. Is `devgiants/filesystem-gpio` is used as a dependency?

Comment: I rephrase things as it was quite unclear. On my actual test, it is not, but eventually it will be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`repositories`](https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md) is a "root only" feature - only root packages can define repositories. If your `filesystem-gpio` package is installed as a dependency, its `repositories` config will be ignored.

> Repositories are only available to the root package and the repositories defined in your dependencies will not be loaded. Read the [FAQ entry](https://getcomposer.org/doc/faqs/why-can't-composer-load-repositories-recursively.md) if you want to learn why.

You should register both packages on packagist or add all repositories in `composer.json` of your root project.